# MVC 4 Issue with @Html.TextAreaFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with one MVC 4 Applicaiton, and facing some small Issue that irritates a lot,

Can any one Help me out?

I have want to make the TextBoxFor Disable or ReadOnly, already tried following:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.EndUserHelp, new { id = "name1", @readonly = 'readonly'});

   $('#name1').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

$('#name1').attr('readonly', true);
```

Hope i will get urget help, Thanks in advance.

Thanks and Regards,
Ruchi Patel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, strings are delimited by double quotes, so:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(
    model => model.EndUserHelp, 
    new { 
        id = "name1", 
        @readonly = "readonly"
    }
)
```

In jQuery you could use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
$('#name1').prop('readonly', true);
$('#name1').prop('readonly', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Property1, 
       new { @class = "ckeditor", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

In the example I used. This method works

Comment: Hello @remzi. The common (and only) language used on StackOverflow is the English. Please update your answer to respect this rule. EDIT: It does not look like an answer in fact, after a quick look on Google Translate...

Comment: sorry :( I fixed it. I did not know